# better design for fact table where each row has a Start & End Date

Tags: data-warehouse, dax, ssas-tabular

My fact table contains details for clients who attend a course.
To ensure i can get a list of clients registered on any particular day, I have not related the date dimension to the fact table.

Instead i created a measure that  does basic between logic (where startDate <= selectedDate && endDate >=SelectedDate)

This allows me to find all clients registered on one single selected day. 
There are a few drawback to this however:

-I have to ensure the report user only selects a single day, i.e. they cannot select a date range.

-I cant easily do counts for samePeriodLastMonth or Year.

Is there a better design i should consider that will still allow me to see counts of registered clients on any given day, along with allowing me to use SamePeriodLastMonth/Year functionality?

Comment: Please post the structure of you fact table and of the time dimension.

Comment: Is the problem with date ranges, and period counts, that you double count the clients? This is easily solved by using a distinct count on the unqiue client code.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind uploading the structure of your fact and dim tables?

Just a thought bubble: if you would like to measure counts for a program over calendar years, I believe you would definitely need to create a Date dimension. Also depending on your reporting needs you might want to consider whether you need an Accumulating Snapshot Fact table.

Please find further details on this:
http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/05/design-tip-145-time-stamping-accumulating-snapshot-fact-tables/

Cheers
Nithin